# PHP filter_var usage recommendations

Tags: php, validation, security

PHPs filter_var function provides both validation and sanitisation. Is it recommended to use these together, or should they be used independently, ie validation for input, sanitisation for output?

Let's pretend I want a user to submit a form including a number. According to [tutsplus](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/sanitize-and-validate-data-with-php-filters--net-2595) I should first sanitise the number, and then validate the output, liks:

```
$number = filter_var($_POST['number'], FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
if (filter_var($number, FILTER_VALIDATE_INT) !== false) {
    // Put number in database, or whatever.
}
```

But is it necessary to run both on input? Wouldn't the sanitisation either return boolean false, or something that the validation would accept?

I'd usually validate first, and then sanitise afterwards to make sure that my input ONLY contains something that validates (ie, not a number followed by letters, like "35p"), but I've been in doubt what would actually be the "proper" way to do this, since I don't know how filter_var works internally, and I can't find a lot about it.

Comment: Why don't you use filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'number', FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT) ; ?

Comment: Maybe filter_has_var() is also interesting for you,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

its not necessary to run both

```
if (filter_var($_POST['number'], FILTER_VALIDATE_INT) !== false) {
        // Put number in database, or whatever.

        echo "hi";
    }
```